# Integral $\int_1^2 x^{-2}\,dx$ with Darboux sums.

Tags: definite-integrals, riemann-sum

I'm trying to calculate $\int_1^2\frac{1}{x^2}\,dx$, with the partition $2^{\frac{i}{n}}$ , $0\leq i\leq n$. ( Darboux sums)

I tried to solve it for hours but I'm getting strange results.

thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is continuous and strictly decreasing, so $$U_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{2^{(k+1)/n}-2^{k/n}}{2^{2k/n}}\\ L_n=\sum_{h=0}^{n-1}\frac{2^{(h+1)/n}-2^{h/n}}{2^{2(h+1)/n}}$$

Thus $$U_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{2^{1/n}-1}{2^{k/n}}=(2^{1/n}-1)\cdot\frac{2^{-n/n}-1}{2^{-1/n}-1}=(2^{1/n}-1)\frac{-\frac12}{2^{-1/n}(1-2^{1/n})}=2^{(1-n)/n}$$ And, to cut it short, $L_n=2^{-2/n}U_n$

Comment: thanks ! but can you explain how did you get rid of the SUM symbol? i dont understand this step.

Comment: The $2^{1/n}-1$ is constant in $k$, so it can be taken out of the sum. Then, it's the sum of a geometric sequence, because $\frac{1}{2^{k/n}}=(2^{-1/n})^k$.

Comment: now i understand , thanks alot! 
little question :when i tried to solve this at the  beggining i used  the infinity geometric sequence formula and it didnt gave me any result. this is not an inifinity geometric sequence?

Comment: @Gyyyy It would give a finite, but incorrect, result. Specifically, roughly twice the correct one, because you'd be adding to what I wrote the sum of all the terms $2^{-k/n}$ for $k\ge n$. Or, in the grand scheme of things, you'd be calculating something fairly close to the definition of $\int_1^\infty x^{-2}\,dx$. The fact that you are summing up to "the same $n$ that appears in $a_1,\cdots, a_n$" is crucial.

Comment: thanks alot for your help!

Comment: We have $n+1$ nodes so $n$ subintervals. But why did you take the summation to $n-1$ instead of $n$?

Comment: And another question please. Did you take the term $2^\frac{i}{n}$ in $U(f,P)$ instead of $2^\frac{i-1}{n}$ for simplicity?

Comment: @nour 1) Because my summation starts at $k=0$ and ends at $k=n-1$. So it has $(n-1)-0+1$ terms. 2) Because the Darboux upper sum forces me to choose $\sup\{ f(x)\,:\, x\in [a_k,a_{k+1}]\}$.

Comment: But in the question $0 \leq i \leq n$ and not $n-1$. Sorry but I'm not catching the idea.

Comment: $0\le i\le n$. In particular, for $i=n$ you have the last point of the interval ($2$). Obviously, $[2,2^{1+\frac1n}]$ is not a subinterval of $[1,2]$.

Comment: Regarding my second question: I meant why didn't you consider $sup{f(x) : x\in [a_{k-1}, a_k]$. I know this is the same. But when I tried to solve it with these terms $2^\frac{i-1}{n}$ made it a little more difficult. That's why I asked you if you use this for more simplicity.

Comment: @Nour Not really. It's the first that came to mind. For yours you should get a general term $$\frac{2^{k/n}-2^{(k-1)/n}}{2^{2(k-1)/n}}=\frac{2^{1/n}-1}{2^{(k-1)/n}}$$ and do basically the same steps (this time summing from $1$ to $n$).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58996/discussion-between-nour-and-g-sassatelli).